# Opening a CashDrawer in C++

Tags: c++, c++builder, epson

At my workplace, we use our own Point Of Sales software which works with Epson Printers TM-U950s connected to 3nStar Mini Cashdrawers. So far, when cash is involved, the software sends a command to the printer in order to open the CashDrawer.

Here is the code for it:

```
void M::OpenDrawer()
{
    FILE *stream;
    try {
        stream = fopen("LPT1", "w");
        fprintf(stream, "%c%c%c%c%c", char(27), char(112), char(0), char(50), char(250));
        fclose(stream);
    } catch(Exception &E) {
        Application->ShowException(&E);
        fclose(stream);
    }
}
```

Our POS software has been working on Windows XP this whole time but we have managed to update it so it can work on Windows 10. However, the previous command won't work. When the TM-U950 gets installed, unlike Windows XP where it uses the existing LPT1 Port, on Windows 10 it creates its own port ESDPRT001. I tried changing the code from

```
stream = fopen("LPT1", "w");
```

to

```
stream = fopen("ESDPRT001", "w");
```

But it won't open the Cashdrawer. I've already searched several websites to verify if the epson command has changed or not, or if we are actually using the right one, and we are. (See http://www.itsmetor.com/wp/epson-esc-commands/)

Long story short, I need help figuring out if the function is the right one to use when sending a direct command to the LPT1 port, so it can open the Cashdrawer, or not, and if possible any advise on how to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: The traditional way devices worked in MS-Windows was that the device name must be specified with a trailing colon, i.e. "LPT1:", although MS-Windows still opened the port if the trailing colon was omitted. Perhaps this is now required in Windows 10.

Comment: Not according to MSDN documentation

Comment: Are you sure `ESDPRT001` is a device name that can be opened using `CreateFile()` (which `fopen()` wraps on Windows) to begin with? I don't think it is.  You might need to setup a [Virtual COM port](http://www.beaglehardware.com/howtovirtualcomport.html) for it ([see also this](http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/3/KPm-TMVirtualPortDriverVer7_UserManual.pdf)), and then you can open the COM port like before

Comment: You are right, @RemyLebeau. Setting up a virtual COM port, assigning the printer to it, and then using the function above mentioned, pointing to the assigned COM port, worked like a charm! Thank you! :D